# Make an ordinary key act as modifier with xcape and xkb

Tags: xkb

To make <kbd>Spacebar</kbd> act as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> under appropriate circumstances, GitHub page of `xcape` currently instructs as follows:

```
# Map an unused modifier's keysym to the spacebar's keycode and make it a
# control modifier. It needs to be an existing key so that emacs won't
# spazz out when you press it. Hyper_L is a good candidate.
spare_modifier="Hyper_L"
xmodmap -e "keycode 65 = $spare_modifier"
xmodmap -e "remove mod4 = $spare_modifier" # hyper_l is mod4 by default
xmodmap -e "add Control = $spare_modifier"

# Map space to an unused keycode (to keep it around for xcape to
# use).
xmodmap -e "keycode any = space"

# Finally use xcape to cause the space bar to generate a space when tapped.
xcape -e "$spare_modifier=space"
```

How to achieve this with `xkb` rather than `xmodmap`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `Hyper_R` in place of `Hyper_L`, it goes like this:

contents of `~/.config/xkb/keycodes/my-keycodes`:

```
xkb_keycodes "xcape-special" {
    <HYPR> =  65;
    <SPCE> = 207;
};
```

Note: `207` is the default keycode for (virtual) `Hyper_R` key in the keycode table loaded on my machine.

contents of `~/.config/xkb/symbols/my-symbols`:

```
xkb_symbols "xcape-special" {
    key <HYPR>  { [ Hyper_R ] };
    modifier_map Control { <HYPR> };
};
```

excerpt from `~/.xinitrc`:

```
XKB_DIR="$HOME/.config/xkb"
XKB_SYMBOL_FILE="my-symbols"
XKB_KEYCODE_FILE="my-keycodes"

setxkbmap -layout "us+$XKB_SYMBOL_FILE(xcape-special)" \
    -keycodes "evdev+$XKB_KEYCODE_FILE(xcape-special)" \
    -option "" -print \
    | xkbcomp -I"$XKB_DIR" - "${DISPLAY%%.*}" >/dev/null 2>&1

xcape -e "Hyper_R=space"
```

This is not the only way to configure `xkb`. Configuration could probably be loaded from a single file with a single `xkbcomp` call. Subdirs of `~/.config/xkb/` merely follow the structure of `/usr/share/X11/xkb/`. The `... -print | xkbcomp ...` part is somewhat convoluted but flexible. At the moment I'm unable to try a simpler setup.

Comment: Could you explain what is going on here?  Is it really necessary to change the keycodes?  Can't it be done in the symbol file?  If this is the only way I'm inclined to stick with xmodmap.

Comment: @Toothrot I don't know if it's possible to do with symbol file alone. Never looked back since then.