# Remap capslock and enter to control modifier

Tags: debian, ubuntu, keyboard-shortcuts, xkb, xcape

I want to remap two keys, not just one.  Specifically, I want to:

1. [Remap](https://askubuntu.com/a/750535) capslock to control and escape, and
2. [Remap](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/326904) return/enter to control when it is pressed with another key.

Based on the two links above, I managed to remap each key separately using xkb and [xcape](https://github.com/alols/xcape), but I couldn't figure out how to remap both keys, capslock and enter by merging the two solutions given above.  I strictly do not want to use xmodmap as it will loose effect after I reboot my Ubuntu 16.04.

Specific code script that accomplishes both tasks 1 and 2 will be appreciated.

Those who use vim or emacs's evil-mode appreciate the significance and convenience of having control key at your home row by hitting capslock and enter!

Comment: can you provide details on how you accomplished these separately?